# How to instantly show added records in a subform in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

After I have successfully added a record in a subform, I have to manually click on the next record and back to view the added record in a subform that contains a query in datasheet view.  I've looked up requery and can't seem to get it to work. I want the new record to show immediately in the query as soon as the user press the "Add Record" button I created.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

I just used the built in command button to add a record.  I also tried using the built in command button to "save record".  I'm guessing I need something to trigger an "after update" or a requery; but do I put it on the command button or where?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code for your "Add Record" button.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you add the record via an SQL insert command to the table behind the subform. Then you need to refresh the subform.

It is faster and smarter to add the record to the RecordsetClone of the subform. This way, no update is needed.